# Access textboxes etc in a class from a form in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I've tried to google, but can't find a answer to my question. I am wondering if I can access a textbox written in moviereview.aspx (for exemple: txtBxId) and then use it in a file called XMLhandler.cs?

Because when I try to create a metod in the XMLhandler.cs I get a message telling me : "The Name 'txtBxId' does not exist in the current context."

Are there any ways I can access this in the XMLhandler.cs file?

Comment: You could, but you will need to pass the textbox (or its owner) to "XMLHandler", presumably from "moviereview.aspx". If you post some code we will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You shouldn't.**

It seems like your class `XMLHandler` is more like a business layer class, where you are handling XML based on some business rules. You should not mix UI with business logic.

The best option would be to have your method accept string parameters, where you can pass your textbox value.

Even better option is to create a Class Library project, have all your business classes there and then you will be able to use the same logic in Web as well as Desktop (other) applications.

Comment: Ah, okei. I thought about using paramters. So I think that I will do that! Thank you

Comment: @Emil, you are welcome, you should see more about [Loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling)